# Can I disable channels in Redactor "Link to entry" feature?

Tags: entries, redactor

I have some channels with entries that I don't want my client to be able to link to using Redactors "Link to entry" feature. Can I disable some channels for a specific field in a specific channel/structure/single?

Comment: Would markdown be an option for you?

Comment: Not following @carlcs. I want some channels not being visible when a user clicks "Link to entry" in the popup.

Comment: I meant markdown instead of Redactor's "Link to entry" feature. See my answer below...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **super** hacky way to do this...but it does do the trick.

1. Locate the JS file responsible for rendering the Element Selector Modal (craft/app/resources/js/compressed/RichTextInput.js)
2. Search for: {storageKey:"RichTextFieldType.LinkToEntry". This is where the modal gets called.
3. Nearby, locate "criteria" and change

   {locale:this.elementLocale} to {locale:this.elementLocale, section: ['sectionYouWant','otherSectionYouWant']}
4. Push this JS file to your server and only the sections you include in the section array above will show entries. The other section titles will show, but no entries will show up to select.

Keep in mind that this adjustment will probably be overriden by any Craft update. I bet building your own redactor plugin would be cleaner.

Comment: Hey check that out! Cheers m8! I'll wait a little to see if Brad or Brandon has any alternatives to this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The Entries Field does have configuration options.

Instead of Redactor, you could use Matrix and combine an Entries Field with a (Plain) Text Field using Markdown syntax.

Example string entered in your Text Field:

```
Bla bla [321 link][1] bla bla
```

And then make your Entries Field return the following:

```
[1]: http://example.com/entry321
```

Then combine the strings in the template and apply the markdown filter.

This is how the Matrix field would look like in the CP:

[image]

Comment: I would consider this very very client un-friendly, sorry :). I would like to use the user-friendly version Redactor provides. Maybe someone else know if it could be done with a little Redactor config-hacking?

Comment: There are clients who love markdown :)

Comment: Then you should meet my clients ;)